# C Pointer Values Being Mixed

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working with a packet capture library and i've got it to print out packet IP addresses to the console using which is working fine:

```
printf("       From: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
printf("         To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));
```

A few lines under that I call a method in a different `.C` file using this passing the IP addresses and port number:

```
addpacket(0, inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src), inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst), ntohs(tcp->th_dport));
```

The method is: `void addpacket(int table, char *srcIP, char *dstIP, int port) {...}`

But inside the `addpacket` method I have this printing to the console:

```
printf("---------------------SRC:%s\n", srcIP);
printf("---------------------DST:%s\n", dstIP);
printf("---------------------PRT:%i\n", port);
```

And I get a result like this:

```
---------------------SRC:192.168.1.64
---------------------DST:192.168.1.64
---------------------PRT:60549
```

where the Source and Destination IP addresses are always the same. I can't find anywhere that i've mixed it up though. If I print this to the console in the original `.C` file the correct IP addresses appear but something seems to be getting mixed up during the method call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` may use a static buffer to store the result, meaning that the second invocation of `inet_ntoa` overwrites the result from the first invocation. Use `inet_ntop` instead, which allows you to supply your own buffers.

Comment: +1. My `inet_ntoa` man page explicitly says "The string returned by `inet_ntoa()` resides in a static memory area."